# Sort by sum of values in a list for dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'a':[{'a1':1},{'a2':5},{'a3':4}], 'b':[{'b1':0},{'b2':1},{'b3':2}], 'c':[{'c1':1},{'c2':2}]}
```

I'd like to sort it by the sum of values in each `list` (values of each item in the dictionary) so that it will result in:

```
r = [('a', (10, [{'a1':1},{'a2':5},{'a3':4}])),
('b', (3, [{'b1':0},{'b2':1},{'b3':2}])),# 'b' and 'c' have sum of '3', so they tied here
('c', (3, [{'c1':1},{'c2':2}]))]
```

I can get this done in a naive approach. I'd like to know how to accomplish this in more Pythonic way. I have tried this, but didn't work for obvious reason:

```
sorted(sum(d.values()), key=d.get, reverse=True)
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Your example result is not valid syntax because the brackets don't match. Fixing the brackets gives a list with one element (a dictionary) which is pointless. Please have another go at your desired output. Also, unless you're using the right version of Python, dictionaries don't have a concept of order, and thus can't be sorted.

Comment: Are the inner dictionaries in `d` always just one key/value? If so it would make more sense to make them pairs (tuples), or to make the list of dicts one dict.

Comment: @AlexHall, Thank you for pointing out the bracket mismatches and the fact that there's no inherent ordering in dictionaries. :) Fixed them in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
d = {'a':[{'a1':1},{'a2':5},{'a3':4}], 'b':[{'b1':0},{'b2':1},{'b3':2}], 'c':[{'c1':1},{'c2':2}]}
new_d = {a:(sum(list(i.values())[0] for i in b), b) for a, b in d.items()}
final_result = sorted(new_d.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1][0], reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
('a', (10, [{'a1': 1}, {'a2': 5}, {'a3': 4}])), ('c', (3, [{'c1': 1}, {'c2': 2}])), ('b', (3, [{'b1': 0}, {'b2': 1}, {'b3': 2}]))]
```

Comment: Please use better variable names than a, b, i, and x.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thank you for the working solution! :) I have a follow-up question about the last line in the code: what does `key=lambda x:x[-1][0]` do? Thank you.

Comment: @user1330974 `lambda x:x[-1][0]` is the sort key. Namely, the value used in the sort comparison.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I think I understand now! :) `new_d.items()` returns iterable of type `dict_items` and each of them in that `dict_items` is processed by `lambda x:x[-1][0]` for sorting. `x[-1]` a way to retrieve the last element in a list. That means it's returning the last inner tuple (e.g., `(10, [{'a1': 1}, {'a2': 5}, {'a3': 4}])` in `('a', (10, [{'a1': 1}, {'a2': 5}, {'a3': 4}]))`) and `x[-1][0]` returns the value of the `sum`. We use that to sort. :) Thanks very much for your help!